# Uglify the javascript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Do I need to use bracket notation for defining the run() block? If i want to minify the javascript files even though run() block is not expecting the any parameters.

here is my code for run block

```
  app.run(function () {
  $(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
      if((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.keyCode == 82 && e.ctrlKey)){
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = $state.current.name;
         var subpath = path.split(".");
         if(subpath.length > 1) {
         if (subpath[1] == 'list')
         $state.reload();
         }else
         $state.reload();
      }else {
        return (e.which || e.keyCode) != 116;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

any help will be appriciated.

Comment: What happen if you test it?

Comment: i'm not yet tested , i need some suggestions so..

Comment: Is uglification synonymous with minification? If not, is there any point to uglification besides obfuscation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are injecting any dependencies u need to do dependency annotation(declare the injection using string) before minifying.

In your case looks like u need inject $state, so u'd better have ur code like:

```
   app.run(['$state',function ($state) {
  $(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
      if((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.keyCode == 82 && e.ctrlKey)){
        e.preventDefault();
        var path = $state.current.name;
         var subpath = path.split(".");
         if(subpath.length > 1) {
         if (subpath[1] == 'list')
         $state.reload();
         }else
         $state.reload();
      }else {
        return (e.which || e.keyCode) != 116;
      }
    });
  });
}]);
```

Then u can uglify it safely.